# Access denied error while installing MongoChef (Studio-3t)

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install mongochef (studio-3t) on my window 10, but at the end i got an error which is

```
Java.io.ioException Access denied error.
```

please help, how to fix it ? (i tried with "run as administration").

Comment: During install or during connect? Sounds more like install and therefore file permissions. Even though it's a tool you "may" use for programming related work, actual "software installation" problems of this type of nature are probably best addressed on sites such as [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). Not a big fan of the 3T products myself, and there are other alternatives out there.

Comment: I suggest contacting the software vendor (3T) for support installing their product.